# How do I compare a time saved in database with the current time?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to compare two times (H:M:S)...

Here's the thing... I want to compare a time saved in a table on my database to the current time that PHP returns to me with `date()`. However, no comparisons are being made as the session variables (`ClassName`, `ClassStartTime` and `ClassBlock`) return me an undefined index (I believe that is because they are not saving anything so I'm trying to access something that doesn't exist).

How do I compare the times?

NOTE: The time in my database is being saved as data-type TIME, that's why I'm not performing a `strtotime()` on the variable `today_time`. Perhaps, that may be my mistake...

```
<?php
        // Obtener hora de registro
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 

        $today_dW = date('w'); // Get number to know the day of the week. Formatted as {Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6}
        $today_time = date('G:i:s'); // Get time. Formatted as {HH : MM : SS}

        /*

        */
        $class_id_query = "SELECT id_materia, bloque FROM horarios WHERE matricula_prof = '" . $_SESSION['TeacherID'] . "' dia_semana = " . $today_dW . " AND hora_inicio >= " . strtotime($today_time) . ""; 

        // Save query result, if any was found, on var 
        $class_id_result = $connection->query($class_id_query);

        // Check if matching result was found to be posted
        if ($class_id_result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
                // Fetch the associated data if any was found
                while($row = $class_id_result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                        $_SESSION['ClassID'] = $row['id_materia'];
                        $_SESSION['ClassStartTime'] = $row['hora_inicio'];
                        $_SESSION['ClassBlock'] = $row['bloque'];
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column `hora_inicio` is of the type `TIME`, you do not need `strtotime`.

```
$class_id_query = "SELECT id_materia, bloque FROM horarios WHERE matricula_prof = '" . $_SESSION['TeacherID'] . "' dia_semana = " . $today_dW . " AND hora_inicio >= '" . $today_time . "'"
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already checked this, but the thing is that I'm not getting the time from the database. I'm getting undefined index on the session variables mentioned above

Comment: manusanram, when you say the query is not being performed, did the query run? You can try to print out the SQL statement string, then perform the query directly in MySQL of phpMyAdmin to see if any results are returned in the first place. Your use of `TIME` data type is correct because I assume you're trying to do a timetable application.

Comment: I've already checked that. The query does run now, It even shows me the information I wanted to recieve.
The application I'm developing is more of a student assitance registry (Whenever a student is absent, it's registered to the database).
However, the use of time works in this manner:

Comment: Teachers log into the page using a code they have. Depending of the time of the day, the page will load which class they're registering and alsoy a list of the students taking said class.

Comment: I did a double-take ... and I realise it didn't run just now not just because you had `strtotime`, but also because you should surround `$today_time` with single quotes. You don't have to do that when you're using `NOW()`. If you use `NOW()`, just ensure that your web server's time is synchronised with your database server's time (if they are on different servers).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I posted an updated version of my code as an answer, you can check it out,,,
Your tip for simulting SQL with phpMyAdmin helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found an answer...
Thanks to @csb I simulated the query using MySQL function TIME, to extract whatever string that was formatted as a time variable to be returned as time...

Since I'm testing with time, all I'm doing right now is filling up certain tables so more information can be returned. I'll keep you updated with the results, tomorrow.

NOTE: I've found another problem... Certain variables inside the session array DO NOT CHANGE even if the query didn't run or returned another result...

```
<?php
    // Get register time
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 

    $_SESSION['DayOfWeek'] = date('w'); 
    // Get number to know the day of the week. Formatted as {Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6}

    /*
        This query must return the class ID, to read its information from the classes table                     
    */
    $class_id_query = "SELECT id_materia, bloque, hora_inicio FROM horarios WHERE matricula_prof = '" . $_SESSION['TeacherID'] . "' AND dia_semana = " . $_SESSION['DayOfWeek'] . "AND TIME(hora_inicio) <= TIME(NOW())"; 

    // Save query result, if any was found, on var 
    $class_id_result = $connection->query($class_id_query);

    // Check if matching result was found to be posted
    if ($class_id_result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // Fetch the associated data if any was found
        while($row = $class_id_result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {   
            $_SESSION['ClassID'] = $row['id_materia'];
            $_SESSION['ClassStartTime'] = $row['hora_inicio'];
            $_SESSION['ClassBlock'] = $row['bloque'];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $_SESSION['ClassID'] = "";
        $_SESSION['ClassStartTime'] = "";
        $_SESSION['ClassBlock'] = "";

        echo "Query for class ID cannot be performed";

        exit();
    }

    /*
        Career logo query.
        Logo on ny part of the system
    */
    // Query for the class information
    $career_logo_query = "SELECT nombre, carrera, cuatrimestre FROM materias WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['ClassID'] . "'";

    // Save query result, if any was found, on var 
    $career_logo_result = $connection->query($career_logo_query);

    // Check if matching result was found to be posted
    if ($career_logo_result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // Fetch the associated data if any was found
        while($row = $career_logo_result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $_SESSION['ClassName'] = $row['nombre'];
            $_SESSION['CareerName'] = $row['carrera'];
            $_SESSION['ClassPeriod'] = $row['cuatrimestre'];

            // Show result at index on screen
            echo $_SESSION['CareerName'];
        }
    }
    ?>_logo.png" alt = "Logotipo de <?php echo $_SESSION['CareerName']; ?>">
```

Here's an update of the code, I'll update tomorrow showing the results.
Thanks again @csb and @Lilthilion for your help and tips.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!
All I needed to do was to transform the time and the query ran, the result i shown below

[The result of the query, changing with the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX1md.png)

Now, all that lasts to be done is to get the students list for the form.
Thanks a lot, everybody.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to compare it with PHP time? What about the database time?

```
$class_id_query = "SELECT id_materia, bloque FROM horarios WHERE matricula_prof = '" . $_SESSION['TeacherID'] . "' dia_semana = " . $today_dW . " AND hora_inicio >= NOW()"
```

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work. The query is not executing...
I added three `echo` calls to print the row, but nothing is being shown on screen

Comment: I think the error is, that you store date and time separately. The timestamp is a combination of both, so you should store them in the same column

Comment: I didn't use timestamp because I thought I have to enter a date and I thought of that as irrelevant.
Here's another thing: I modified the query string to just use the condition of the TeacherID, and STILL the query is not performed.

Comment: Well, nevermind, the whole query gets messed up with the time. It works fine with the TeacherID and DayOfWeek. So how do I use exactly the timestamp @Lithilion ?

Comment: Lithilion timestamp is not the right data type imho, because it seems the app is some sort of timetable